# Button text appearing outside frame

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I have a UIButton set up in the interface builder and I have the following code in the `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
purchaseButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 8
purchaseButtonOutlet.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
purchaseButtonOutlet.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

On bigger devices e.g. the iPad Pro, it works fine, but on smaller devices e.g. the iPhone SE, it doesn't work:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: check your button frame

Comment: try minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

Comment: As the property name suggests adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth only works on the width and your text fits width wise.  If you want it for height as well you will have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set two constraints

1. Vertically center to container
2. Add 10 to left constraint